# Find the equations of the tangent line to the curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the surface $z = 2x^2 + y^2$:

The plane $y=3$ intersects the surface in a curve. Find the equations of the tangent line to this curve at x = 2.

From my understanding, to get the curve I would plug in $y = 3$, so $z=2x^2 + 9$ is the curve. The tangent line to this curve would be the derivate with respect to $x$, therefor my tangent line is $z = 4x$. And at $x=2$ we simply have $z=8$.

This however is incorrect according to the back of the book as it has the answer as: $y=3$, $z=8x+1$

Could someone please explain to me where my understanding is failing and what would be the correct interpretation?

Comment: Even in one dimension, the derivative is not the tangent line.  The derivative is the *slope* of the tangent line.  I am also somewhat confused–when you say "the" tangent line, do you mean the line in the plane $y=3$ that is tangent to the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I am somewhat confused by the statement of the question, so let me try to clarify that, then answer the question that I pose:

> The surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the equation
>   $$ z = 2x^2 + y^2 $$
>   intersects the plane $y=3$ in a curve.  Find the equations of the line in the plane $y=3$ that is tangent to this curve at $x=2$.

The plane $y=3$ is an isometric copy of the plane $\{(x,z):x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  Making the obvious identification, this means that we are asked to find a line tangent to the curve
$$ z = 2x^2 + 9 $$
at $x=2$ in the $(x,z)$-plane.  The equation of this line is given by
$$ z - z_0 = m(x-x_0), $$
where $(x_0,z_0)$ is a point that the line passes through, and $m$ is the slope of that line.

To get the point, note that we are looking for a line tangent to the curve when $x=2$.  When $x=2$, we have $z = 2(2)^2 + 9 = 17$, thus we obtain $(x_0, z_0) = (2,17)$.  For the slope, recall that this is given by the derivative.  Thus $m$, the slope, is given by
$$ m = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=2} = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (2x^2 + 9)\right|_{x=2} = \left.4x\right|_{x=2} = 8. $$

Putting this together, we obtain the equation for the line:
$$ z - 17 = 8(x-2)
\implies z = 8x + 1.$$

As pointed out by amd in the comments below, this isn't entirely a complete solution.  Up above, we made the identification of the $(x,z)$-plane with the plane $y=3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The answer above assumes implicitly that $y=3$.  To put the line we found back into $\mathbb{R}^3$, we should "undo" this identification.  Specifically, the line we are interested in is the set of points
$$ \left\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : z=8x+1, y=3 \right\}.$$
In the context of the original question, I suspect that the *equations* (note the plural) desired are the two on the right, i.e.
$$ z=8x+1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad y=3. $$

Comment: Your last equation is that of a plane. You need to add the equation $y=3$ to get the line.

Comment: @amd I had already made the simplification that the only plane that I was working in was the $y=3$ plane (with the obvious identification).  However, it seems that I was not clear enough about that, so I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You are asked to find the tangent to the curve $z = 2x^2+9$ at the point $x = 2$. Note that a tangent *line* is specified by a *slope*,and a *point on that line*. You do not seem to have specified the point, although you have specified the slope.

The slope, indeed, is given by the derivative, which at $x = 2$ is $4x = 8$. That is computed by you.

To find the point, simply substitute $x = 2$ in $z = 2x^2+9$ to get the point $(2,17)$ , which will definitely lie on the tangent line.

Now, the equation of the line in Cartesian coordinates would then be given by $(z - 17) = 8(x  - 2)$. This simplifies to $z = 8x+1$, giving you the desired answer.